# Buscar registros filtrando por count de uma subconsulta

Tags: sql, oracle, pl-sql

estou com o seguinte problema:
Tenho tres tabelas e preciso mostrar o registro do funcionario apenas quando o ele tiver 1 e apenas 1 dependente. E também deve ter 0 e no maximo 1 registro de premio, conforme estrutura abaixo, que neste caso apenas o funcionario de id 3 e 4 devem ser exibidos:

[image: Funcionarios]

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Na minha query executei os counts conforme abaixo:

```
//total premios igual a 0 ou 1
SELECT COUNT(pre.qtd) AS total_premios
FROM premios pre
INNER JOIN funcionarios fun ON fun.id = pre.id_func
GROUP BY fun.id

//total dependentes igual a 1 e apenas 1    
SELECT COUNT(1) AS total_dependentes
FROM dependentes dep
INNER JOIN funcionarios fun ON fun.id = dep.cod_func
GROUP BY fun.id
```

Agora se tentar usar ela dentro da minha query eu nao consigo usar os alias para fazer a regra na condicao do where conforme abaixo, alguem poderia me auxiliar?

```
SELECT f1.name
  (SELECT COUNT(pre.qtd)
   FROM premios pre
   INNER JOIN funcionarios fun ON fun.id = pre.id_func
   GROUP BY fun.id) AS total_premios,

  (SELECT COUNT(1)
   FROM dependentes dep
   INNER JOIN funcionarios fun ON fun.id = dep.cod_func
   GROUP BY fun.id) AS total_dependentes
FROM funcionarios f1

//A CONDICAO WHERE EU NAO CONSEGUI FAZER FUNCIONAR PQ NAO RECONHECE OS CAMPOS
WHERE total_dependentes = 1  AND (total_premios = 0  OR total_premios = 1)
```

**Demo:** [SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/c6bfc4/2)

Answer (score 1):

Olá viva como não partilhaste o teu exemplo no SQLFiddle, partilho uma possível sollução mas sem testar no teu exemplo:

```
SELECT * FROM (
SELECT f1.name, 
  (SELECT COUNT(pre.qtd)
                       FROM premios pre
                       INNER JOIN funcionarios fun ON fun.id = pre.id_func
                    ) AS total_premios,
  (SELECT COUNT(1)
                       FROM dependentes dep
                       INNER JOIN funcionarios fun ON fun.id = dep.cod_func) AS total_dependentes
FROM funcionarios f1
GROUP BY f1.name) tb
WHERE total_dependentes = 1 AND (total_premios = 0  OR total_premios = 1)
```

Comment: group by nao funcionaria assim, pq retorna mais de um registro

Comment: Como indiquei, não tinhas o exemplo para testar não reparei num pormenor, verifiquei que criaste no SQLFiddle, isso ajuda muito. Não precisas de um group by num subselect de um count, verifica agora a query que coloquei, corrigida.